# For loop is skipping some cells when trying to format with Openpyxl

Tags: python, for-loop, openpyxl

So I have this code that cleans up an Excel file and it all works pretty good, but something odd is happening where some of my cells randomly do not have their style updated.  I have columns 10-12 set to date_style as defined in my code, but sometimes the cells in the sheet are not updating.  Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font
import openpyxl, os

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Opportunities.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb['OpportunityList']
date_style = NamedStyle(name='datetime', number_format='MM/DD/YYYY')
bold = Font(bold=True)
no_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None)

print('Deleting row ' + str(sheet.max_row))
sheet.delete_rows(sheet.max_row)

#Loop through the rows and update/delete as needed
for rowNum in range(sheet.max_row, 1, -1):  #start with the last row
    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 10).value = datetime.strptime\
    (sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 10).value, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 11).value = datetime.strptime\
    (sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 11).value, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 12).value = datetime.strptime\
    (sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 12).value, '%m/%d/%Y').date()

    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 10).style = date_style
    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 11).style = date_style
    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 12).style = date_style

    if sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 10).value <=\
    datetime.strptime('7/31/2017', "%m/%d/%Y").date():
        print('Deleting row ' + str(rowNum))
        sheet.delete_rows(rowNum)
    if sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 4).value ==\
    'Open' and sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 11).value <=\
    datetime.strptime('12/31/2016', "%m/%d/%Y").date():
        print('Deleting row ' + str(rowNum))
        sheet.delete_rows(rowNum)
    if sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 10).value <\
    sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 11).value:
        sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 11).value =\
        sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 10).value

for rowNum in sheet['1:1']:
    rowNum.font = bold
    rowNum.fill = no_fill

for col in sheet.columns:
     column = col[0].column # Get the column name
     sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 20

wb.save('Updated_Opportunities.xlsx')
```

See a screenshot to see what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, some cells maintain the default 'yyyy-mm-dd' style and I don't know why.  All 3 column are originally text columns, so the for loop is definitely updating them to a date type, it's just the format part that sometimes fails. Almost all the cells in all 3 columns update, but there's a few outliers and I don't have an explanation for it.  It's not a big deal, but I'm a beginner, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong in the for loop without knowing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you remove items from an iterable while looping over it, you'll mess up the internal counter.

Comment: @CharlieClark That's why I'm going from bottom row to top row.  I didn't think that would be an issue and even then, when formatting for a cell isn't applied, you can see that for the other cells in that same row, it is applied just fine

Comment: Okay I've solved the problem by doing the deleting first and placing the formatting in a second for loop under it.  I still have no idea what's going on with the original, if the entire row was affected by bad formatting, perhaps I could make some sense of how the deleting of rows was affecting it, but hence, I cannot.  Oh well, problem solved

Comment: FWIW you could set `guess_types = True` for the workbook where openpyxl will try and convert numbers formatted as text to the correct type but it is better to use your own code for it in which case I'd suggest using a function to make the code easier to read and maintain. Also, use `ws.iter_rows(min_col=10, max, max_col=12)` to give you just the cells you need.